# Getting ThrottlingException: Rate exceeded, status code: 400 on AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-go

I have 110 Fargate tasks running (not always in parallel). I am trying to get lambdas from other AWS accounts (through CrossAccountRole) using "ListFunctions" call as guided on the AWS SDK - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/#Lambda.ListFunctions

I sometimes get a Throttling error, while making the (SDK) API call:
**ThrottlingException: Rate exceeded, status code: 400**

Also have gone through this solution - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html

Wanted to understand whether the AWS SDK Service (lambda) already implements it. Do I need a custom implementation of retries in my case or just increase the rate limit of Fargate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the docs you posted:

> In addition to simple retries, **each AWS SDK implements** exponential backoff algorithm for better flow control.

This is further clarified in the [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-api-throttling-errors/):

> Note: Each AWS **SDK implements** automatic retry logic and exponential backoff algorithms.
>
> Do I need a custom implementation of retries in my case or just increase the rate limit of Fargate?

If you use AWS SDK, you don't have to implement anything special. However, you your exception can be related to [AWS Lambda function scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html):

> When requests come in faster than your function can scale, or when your function is at maximum concurrency, additional requests fail with a **throttling error** (429 status code).

Thus if you think that you are hitting your **concurrency limits** on lambda, which could be due to large number of Fargate tasks, you can consider asking the AWS support for its increase. Default limit is 1000, which seems to be sufficient for your tasks. But maybe the other account is also running other lambdas. The **1000 limit is for all functions** in an account and region.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
Just wanted to say that I am not getting 429, I am getting a 400 (Bad Request) - ThrottlingException when making the AWS API call (to fetch the no. of lambdas in the target account from the master account, using CrossAccountRole).
I am making this call from the ECS Fargate task using ListFunctions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/#Lambda.ListFunctions). Wondering how changing the Lambda concurrency limit would help there?

Comment: Also, you are correct about "AWS SDK implementing exponential backoff algorithm for better flow control", but there are docs mentioning that sometimes the client should customize it. Wanted to understand if there's a way that I can experiment with customizing the request.Retryer interface for retries and exponential backoff.

Comment: Sure, is there any example on how I can go about implementing it? I am very new to AWS and Go, not exactly sure how to customize it (basically to increase retry on a special case for Throttling)

Comment: @ShivikaSodhi In the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) there is a pseudo-code on how to implement the backoff.